# Mails not being downloaded over company WiFi

Tags: networking, email, firewall, blocking, pop3

We have a problem at our company where during high traffic hours (starting around 8am) clients are dropping the mail server connection and cannot download mails (our mail server is hosted outside of the company). There are no problems with the internet access itself, it just seems to block incoming mails (clients are mostly using pop3 on port 110 or 995).

We checked the firewall, but it has no logs about blocking anything and its configuration should not be the problem. What could be another reason for such behaviour that I should check next? Could it be a block on the ISP side of things? What else could implement some sort of block, a router/DNS server/AP?

Comment: Start a packet capture on the mail server: does it receive the connection attempts (TCP SYNs)? does it respond to them?

Comment: Does your company have an IT department?